# Laravel Sum column database Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Trying to get the sum of a int field in one of my table should be pretty easy, unfortunately it is not as I'm getting different result whether I use Laravel, MySQL or Excel.

Laravel 5.4 gives me **20506**:

```
Table::sum('field_name');
```

MySQL gives me **1830**:

```
Select sum(field_name) from table;
```

And the data from the Excel sheet before importing it into the database:
Sum gives me **145689**

Any idea? I tried to cast to integer before doing the sum but it doesn't work.
All the numbers are pretty big but don't contain comma or dot.

Examples of values I have to sum: (contain sometimes empty cells)

```
17906774
99630157
28581131

159551532
20312892
668928885
```

Comment: What do you get if you do a foreach sum of all rows in laravel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$query = YourModel::query();
$query->withCount([
'activity AS yoursum' => function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount_total) as paidsum"))->where('status', 'paid');
    }
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: I agree with Toby and I can see after many years no explanation has been added. That's why I'm downvoting.

Answer (score 5):

You can use laravel aggregate function SUM as :

```
$result = DB::table('table_name')
                ->select(DB::raw('SUM(field_name) as total_field_name'))
                ->get();
```

For more details you can follow:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Thanks

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$result = DB::table(tablename)
->selectRaw('sum(column)')
->get();
```

If it still gives you wrong result, maybe wait for someone to give you a better answer. This is all I could think of.

Comment: This gives me the same result as the SQL query: Select sum(field_name) from table;