# How to perform a multi table select using eloquent on Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have the following scenario:

1 - One invoice can have many items (goods or services), each good or service is sold with its own price. (Invoice_items table). In this case if we want to know the total amount of an invoice we kind of sum the amount of the items associated with it.

2 - An invoice can be paid via many receipts. So if we want to know if an invoice is totally paid we sum the amount paid on each receipt_item.

For more details about the scenario check the attached diagram.

I want two eloquent queries or something, that can help me to:
[image: ry]

1. retrieve all invoices that are not paid.
2. Check from a query if a single invoice is paid or not.

Please consider that in my Invoice Model I have:

```
public function invoiceItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InvoiceItem::class, 'invoices_id');
    }


 public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class, 'invoices_id');
    }
```

Comment: you should learn https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: In my models i've configured all the relationships for this case.

Comment: then what error your r getting have u done any research ?

Comment: I have edited the question to provide more details about the relationships.

Comment: I have done a research of course @KamleshPaul.

Comment: so what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I am thinking in a way of comparing the values of the sum of the invoice_items and the receipt_item. But i dont know how to perform it.

Comment: then do some research and come up with anything

Comment: @KamleshPaul If you know or have any idea how to get out of this alley, I would appreciate it, since if I got here I already exhausted all other search engines.

Comment: Try with the sections "querying relationship existence" and querying relationship absence in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: @Chuy I have gone thru there, actually the solutions passes from there. However just query the existence or absense of a relationship does not proove that an invoice is paid or not.  In this case we have to somehow compare values.

Comment: You can chain eloquent methods to your relationship, like $model->related()->where(DO THE COMPARISON HERE)->get() (or ->first() if you want single result).

Answer (score 0):

You may [append an attribute](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json) to your invoice model, for example:

```
$appends = ['is_paid'];
```

This property needs an accessor (read the docs about accessors):

```
public function getIsPaidAttribute () {
    // here you can make the calculation and return a true/false value
}
```

Now, in your controller, you can get your invoices and filter using the `invoice.is_paid` attribute.

```
// retrieve all invoices
// you might need to add where conditions to lighten up 
// the results if you have thousands of records
$invoices = Invoice::all();

// filter paid invoices
$paidInvoices = $invoices->filter(function($i){
     return $i->is_paid === true;
});
```

And finally, if you want to know if an invoice is paid just ask for `$invoice->is_paid`.

Comment: Good approach, Good idea, actually it is working this way right now. but On future occasions I see that there may be memory leaks since paid filters are made via Eloquent Collections, ie after consultation. I want to perform it on the query.

Comment: True, you wil have to use where() instead of Invoice::all(), and maybe use a boolean column to do the filtering easier for the query. Also you may use the query builder to perform your query. This could be a good starting point i think: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47204579/173299